# How to add calculated fields in pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table, calculated-field

Suppose I have a pivot like this:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Col_A': [1,2,3,3,3,4,9,9,10,11], 
     'Col_B': ['A','K','E','E','H','A','J','A','L','A'],
     'Value1':[648,654,234,873,248,45,67,94,180,120],
     'Value2':[180,120,35,654,789,34,567,21,235,83],
     'Value3':[567,21,235,83,248,45,67,94,180,120]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_pvt = pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Value1'], index='Col_A', columns='Col_B', aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
df_pvt
```

[image]

I want to add a calculated field at the right side of the pivot using "Value2/Value3". This calculated field should also display with Col_B categories. One way to do it is to add Value2, and Value3 in the pivot and do the division afterwards. Then, I could just drop those Value 2 and Value 3 sections in the pivot. However, I'm wondering if there's any easier way to achieve this. I've tried the following, but didn't work:

```
pd.pivot_table(df,values=['Value1','Value2'/'Value3'], index='Col_A', columns=['Col_B','val2/val3'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
```

Comment: kindly add your expected output dataframe

Comment: Sorry, this is in pivot format. I'm not sure how I can type out an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply these transformations before the pivot:

```py
df = df.groupby(['Col_A', 'Col_B']).sum()
df = df.eval('V23 = Value2 / Value3')[['Value1', 'V23']]
```

Then apply the pivot and clean-up:

```py
df.reset_index().pivot(index='Col_A', columns='Col_B').fillna(0)
```

**UPDATE**:
In fact, you can replace the last line with just:

```py
df.unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it generated the desired output. However, could you explain what ```df.eval()``` do?

Comment: it returns you a new dataframe, having applied an arbitrary operation. In this case assign could be used too but with eval you can just use the column names without having to refer to the df 3 times.

Comment: With an upvote, could you edit your post with a screenshot of your result output. Easier for other people to see in the future as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `assign` after:

```
out = df.pivot_table('Value1', 'Col_A', 'Col_B', aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0) \
        .assign(Value4=df.groupby('Col_A')
                         .apply(lambda x: sum(x['Value2']) / sum(x['Value3'])))
print(out)

# Output:
Col_B      A       E      H     J      K      L    Value4
Col_A                                                    
1      648.0     0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0  0.317460
2        0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0  654.0    0.0  5.714286
3        0.0  1107.0  248.0   0.0    0.0    0.0  2.611307
4       45.0     0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0  0.755556
9       94.0     0.0    0.0  67.0    0.0    0.0  3.652174
10       0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0  180.0  1.305556
11     120.0     0.0    0.0   0.0    0.0    0.0  0.691667
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants, which is `sum(Value2)/sum(Value3)`...

Comment: @QuangHoang. Thanks. This is the result of `df.groupby('Col_A').apply(lambda x: sum(x['Value2']) / sum(x['Value3')))`?